# sharepoint 2013 contact web part display

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to alter the contact web part to display the text below the image?  I have tried editing the web-part but there doesn't seem to be anywhere I can change this.  I was expecting to be able to 'float' the image but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript solution is possible. Use the below javascript code in a content editor web part on the page.

```
$(".ms-descriptiontext").parent().parent().parent().append("<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>"+$(".ms-descriptiontext").text()+"</td></tr>")
$(".ms-descriptiontext").hide();
```

You can replace ".ms-descriptiontext" with any other selector.

[image]